# Can Hosted Office 365 data be downloaded locally for large-scale backups?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, backup

This is (no longer) a hypothetical question from a potential customer.

They use O365 and use the hosted cloud option for O365 data from Microsoft. What they want is to make local copies of all their 'data'. They have emails, Office Documents, Sharepoint etc. etc.. There are probably 100 + employees and they are looking for a solution that can replicate the O365 cloud data locally.

Is there a way to get daily dumps of all their corporate cloud data so that they can maintain local copies?

If so can this process be automated?

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome as I do not have much familiarity with MS Office 365.

Comment: There are two versions of Office 365.  One is a hosted solution where everything is in the cloud.  The other is a subscription to the desktop clients.  Which version is the customer using?  In the hosted solution, of course the emails can be copied locally, that is up to the email client to handle.  In the other case the files are already local.

Comment: I think what you are asking is that if you can download..  Or rather save documents to your local drive rather than Live Drive (formerly Skydrive).  You should be able to change where you save the files in Word, Excel, etc. to point to your local Documents.  If you want to keep saving the files to the live drive, and copy the files from there..  You could use a Windows Scheduled Task to copy from Live drive to your My Documents using Xcopy...

Comment: They are most likely using the hosted version. And lets also assume that there are hundred of GB of data in the cloud.

Comment: @datUser - This is the problem with hypothetical questions.  You need to find out.  But in either case a document in the cloud can be stored locally. So the question itself is not even all that clear. *Please edit your question so it isn't a hypothetical question.*

Comment: @Leptonator I am not sure a solution where individual users store their documents locally is quite scalable enough. They want to do full O365 backups locally.

Comment: @datUser - It is dead simple to backup  the contents of the professional version of OneDrive which uses Sharepoint as a backend to a network drive.  I cannot answer a hypothetical question though.

Comment: @datUser I am confused.  What do you mean?  Store the documents locally is "quite scalable" enough?  I think you have this backward.  The point being, is that if the local drive / hardware goes bad, you have the document in the cloud.  Understand, you customer is driving the point.

Comment: @Ramhound Noted;edited.

Comment: @Leptonator By 'scalable' I mean I would not want to suggest that each user change their configuration for Mail, Excel, Word to save all of this data locally, to their workstation. But this may not be what you were suggesting. If I misunderstood what you were suggesting, then please feel free to elaborate. Forgive my relative ignorance of how MS does the O365 thing as I do not use this service - hence my question.

Comment: OK..  Now we are getting somewhere..  You can deploy a GPO/LGPO to change the settings from AD to do this.

Comment: @Leptonator so if I am following you correctly, you would recommend that they change the settings in each of their O365 products to simply keep local copies of their data on each workstation and rely on individual workstation backups to make their O365 data available locally?

Comment: Office 365  versions of Word and Excel don't require you store the files in the cloud.  In relation to Exchange and Office 365, emails will exist on the server, but you can make local copies of the emails to the .PST.  OneDrive/Sharepoint files can be archived as needed.

Comment: To @Ramhound s point..  You can create your MST or Transforms file when installing Office 365, to automatically set the folders for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is no single facility for making this happen.  You will most likely want a 3rd party service or application to help you.  You have at the very least two different mechanisms you need to plan for.

Mail - you need Exchange based system.  There are products that can use the web services to download messages to a central store.  Other options are to use local PST files, or secondary IMAP clients to get mail.  It's a bit clunky but it's possible to do with a little up front effort.

For SharePoint/OneDrive - There are no export methods available directly.  You can map to document libraries and copy out the data (script it if you need nightly, etc).

Beyond those methods you need to look at using a 3rd party tools.  Most O365 tools will come in the two flavors above so you may need more than one.  For Mail - you are going to either pull it from the service, or place a service/appliance in front which captures all the data and stores it.  SharePoint can only pull from API's so you need a tool that can extract data.

I would take a look at MetaLogix, AvePoint, and ShareGate as potential tools to use.

If they are looking for ways to protect their data - bear in mind there are layers of tools available in O365.  Depending on your subscription level you may be able to take advantage of legal hold and archive mailboxes for mail (keeps mail from being deleted), as well as document version control, extended recycle bin option, and permission controls (like removing delete ability and requiring another channel to remove documents). These are more advanced topics - but they are available, and upgrading the subscription may be cheaper than tools mentioned above.